# Magento2.3 - My saleable quantity is reducing twice after placing an order

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.3, inventory, qty, reservations

After creating an order with `qty = 5` I see that the saleable quantity of that product reduces by `10`.

I already checked the table `inventory_reservation` and two rows where created:

- Attached the screen shot here.

[image]

Is there something I can do to stop this from happening?

Thanks!